# Is using Google Sheets API free or not?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using the Google Sheets API through googleapis npm package.
Do i have to keep a billing account enabled to be on safer side if the limits exhaust in production.

Also, is the google sheets API free? If not how to track the charges getting incurred for using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Google Sheets API is completely free, just make sure you stay within your [quota limits](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits).*